# IntelliJ doesn't recognize class of gradle dependency

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, javafx, build

I have the following problem. I added the AnimateFX dependency via "Dependencies" tab in IntelliJ IDEA when I try to use one of the classes, it won't recognize it. Intellisense wont't list it either.

[IntelliJ Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Znsi.png)

Does anyone have an idea, what the actual problem here is?

To reproduce:

1. Create new JavaFX project via *File* - *New* - *Project...* choose *Gradle* as *Build System* and *jdk-15*(I downloaded it via IntelliJ) as *Project SDK*:
   [Project Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4xnx.png)
2. Click *Next*, don't add any dependencies shown in the following dailog: [Dependencies Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yvobr.png)
3. Click *Finish*
4. After project configuration is finished, open *gradle.build* and add the following implementation statement to *dependencies*

> *implementation 'io.github.typhon0:AnimateFX:1.2.1'*

5. Load gradle changes
6. Go to a .java class file that is in the *src* folder and try to use any class of the AnimateFX dependency, e.g.:

> FadeIn fadeInTransition = new FadeIn(anyNode);

IntelliJ should now give an error stating the following: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0SO3.png)

IntelliJ version: IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.2 (Community Edition) - Build #IC-212.5284.40

Gradle version: 7.1.1

Also, this is the content of my gradle.build:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.10'
}

group 'de.mwllpr'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = '15'
targetCompatibility = '15'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

application {
    mainModule = 'de.mwllpr.application'
    mainClass = 'de.mwllpr.application.GameApplication'
}

javafx {
    version = '15.0.1'
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.14.1'
    implementation 'io.github.typhon0:AnimateFX:1.2.1'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:3.12.4'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

and module-info.java:

```
module de.mwllpr.application {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires org.apache.logging.log4j.core;
    requires org.apache.logging.log4j;

    opens de.mwllpr.application to javafx.fxml;
    exports de.mwllpr.application;
}
```

Zipped demo project: http://www.filedropper.com/demofx

Comment: If the project is Gradle based, all the dependencies must be added via `build.gradle` file, not using the Dependencies UI.

Comment: I tried both… doesn‘t work either. I also tried to invalidate caches. I checked module dependencies, everything there seems to be correct…

Comment: Please provide the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @CrazyCoder i updated my original post. hope you are able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please share a sample project zipped.

Comment: See the latest edit above.

Comment: It looks like the library you are trying to use doesn't support Java modules. Delete `module-info.java` from the project and it should help.

Comment: Thought so as well and tried this already. That solves compile time errors, but as soon as you run the project, it will give an error message about missing JavaFX information. Which I can fix by adding JVM options. But, aren‘t non-modular JARs so called „automatic modules“, that should get placed at the module path via gradle?

Comment: So the issue is not IntelliJ IDEA specific as you get the errors in Gradle as well.